# Plotting a companys growth rate

Tags: python

A company produces an item. In the production of the items is the growth rate of the cost and the income given by:

K'(x) = 0.003x + 31

I'(x) = -0.01x + 50

Where x is the amount of items/goods and x ∈ (0,850) Initial conditions is K(0) = 3000 and I(0) = 0

a) Plot K(x) and I(x) in norwegian kroners

b) When is the profit the biggest

Can someone show how they would have done this type of task? Thanks in advance

Comment: a company produces goods. Rather

Comment: What have you tried so far? How do the results differ from what you want? Please keep in mind that Stack Overflow is not a free homework service.

Comment: @rolfi check out the math module

Comment: @NicholasHunter https://ideone.com/8qtjCj this is what I have done so far, but I fear it is completely wrong...